# How many overs are required to bowl to avoid reserve day in the final of World T20 2014?

Tags: cricket, cricket-world-cup

How many overs are required to bowl to avoid reserve day in the final of World T20 2014?

I see a day reserve day in Cricinfo fixtures.

Comment: I think world T20i is different from world cup. Anyway, the tag can be used for world T20i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserve day is used only if the match is not completed even after applying the D/L method. So if it is not possible to complete full quota of the innings (i.e. 20 overs in T20 matches), the D/L method is applied which requires minimum **[5 overs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duckworth%E2%80%93Lewis_method#Application)** to be played per side in T20 matches.

That means if both teams play minimum **5 overs** each, the match will be completed and the reserve day will be avoided.